# Quantum orbit method at roots of unity

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, poisson-geometry

Chari and Pressley’s *A guide to quantum groups*, or the original work by Vaksman and Soibelman in 1989, explains that, similarly to the orbit method which relates quantised coadjoint orbits to unitary irreducible representations, there is a relation between dressing orbits of a compact Lie group $G$ and the representation theory of the corresponding quantum group $U_q(g)$.

Does this remain true when $q$ is a root of unity?